# Pasta resources sumindo ao dar clone

Tags: eclipse

estou com o seguinte problema, após dar clone no git as seguintes pastas desaparecem e não consigo coloca-las novamente nesse estado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém saberia como configurar pra elas voltarem?

Comment: Você tá importando como projeto do Maven?

Comment: Sim, estou importando.